# Найти номер строки GoogleSheets API по значению в ячейке

Tags: python, api, google-spreadsheet

Имеется гугл таблица.
Задача:
Найти ячейку по точному соответствию значения поиска. Значение уникальное в рамках столбца.
Вернуть номер строки найденной ячейки.

Никак не могу найти метод в документации API Sheets, который бы мне помог.
Есть вариант получить всё, преобразовать в датафрейм, выполнить поиск уже в датафрейме. Но не хочется усложнять. Возможно, есть стандартные методы API, которые могут мне помочь?

Кто-то может посоветовать варианты решения?

Comment: Похоже такого метода и нет. Придется усложнять.

Answer (score 0):

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

#аутентификацию пропустил

#Получение данных из листа

worksheet = spreadsheet.sheet1  # Выберите нужный лист по индексу или имени

#Найти ячейку 
date_cell = worksheet.find('Значение') # я искал с датой

#Получение номера строки найденной ячейки
row_number = date_cell.row

print("Номер строки: ", row_number) # мы великолепны
```